# How can I visualize a HTML5 playable ad on Facebook, to test that it works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I created a playable ad using HTML5, and would like to show it on Facebook.

I am able to preview the ad when I create the ad campaign, but once I publish it, I can't seem to get a link to test it out.

The "preview" buttons show me previews of just the opening video, not the interactive part.

Any help would be appreciated!